# For variables that can be declared in each code area

Tags: c#

I don't know what to define my question.
Let's say that the code below names each area A, B, C, some types are declarable and some are impossible.
I want to know about this difference.

(The code is just example of a deligate.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// Area A

delegate int MyDelegate(int a, int b);
public enum myenum { a,b,c };
class another { }
//int a; you can't 
//void func(int a); you can't

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    // Area B

    class A
    {
        // Area C

        public int Func(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    }
    class Program
    {
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            MyDelegate d = new MyDelegate(a.Func);
            d(1,2);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me about this? Or what should I search for?

I tried to declare a variable in each different area. I think blocked it due to the problem of the global variable, but I want to know the details.

Comment: It's unclear why you've tried to muddy the water with delegates here. Fields can only be declared in classes and structs. Local variables can be declared in methods, constructors etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you can only define types (classes, structures, enums, delegates) in areas A and B. Area A is outside the namespace declaration so any types declared there will be members of the root namespace. Area B is inside the namespace declaration so types declared there will be members of that namespace.

Area C is inside a type (the `A` class) so you can declare any type members there (nested types, fields, properties, methods, events).